# Cisco Anyconnect on Mac can't resolve VPN domain name behind proxy

Tags: macos, cisco-vpn-client

I try to use Cisco Anyconnect client 4.4.03034 on Mac which is behind proxy.

I enter VPN domain name, press "Connect" button and get the following error:

> The vpn connection failed due to unsuccessful domain name resolution.

This is obviously caused by the machine behind proxy. I.e. i have to `export http_proxy` in command line or setup it for different software to make things work.

In System preferences -> Network -> Advanced -> Proxies i have "Automatic proxy configuration" enabled pointing on the *.pac configuration file. Unfortunately looks like Anyconnect on Mac does not know anything about system proxy settings.

I have Windows machine behind the same proxy and looks like Cisco Anyconnect there uses Internet Explorer proxy settings. Unfortunately on Mac i do not know how to let it know about system proxy. Any ideas? Maybe some command line options for anyconnect client or configuration file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found two ways to use AnyConnect VPN behind proxy on MacOS.

- You can download *Anyconnect Profile Editor* and create XML configuration which will force the AnyConnect to use specified proxy. Put the configuration under `/opt/cisco/anyconnect/profile/MyCustomProfile.xml` (you can see the most important part of such configuration below):

> ```
> <AnyConnectProfile>
>     <ClientInitialization>
>         <ProxySettings>Override
>             <PublicProxyServerAddress UserControllable="true">1.3.3.7:1337</PublicProxyServerAddress>
>         </ProxySettings>
>     </ClientInitialization>
> </AnyConnectProfile>
> ```

- or you can simply [setup OpenConnect for Mac](https://gist.github.com/moklett/3170636) which I found a more easy solution which also does not override your routing table.